# How to define url which accept everykind of strings in django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

In django, I defined  url like that

```
(r'^checkstring/(?P<string>\w+)/$',views.check_str,name='check str')
```

But, When i  enter string inputs like ibrahim.yilmaz, ibrahi!m or ibrahim@ibrahim.com, it returns http 404.
So  how can i write the url  which accept  everykind of string?

any help will be appreciated.

İbrahim

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Django uses regular expressions to match incoming requests. In python a dot (.) matches any character except a newline.  See [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) for more information and try:

```
(r'^checkstring/(?P<string>.+)/$',views.check_str,name='check str')
```

Also keep in mind that this will accept any character (including the forward slash) which may not be desirable for you.  Be sure to test to make sure everything works as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

In Django >= 2.0, you can implement in the following way.

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('polls/<string>/$','polls.views.detail')
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Django 2.0**

---

import **re_path** in **urls.py** file
like this:
**from** django.urls **import** re_path

then in the urlpatterns write the following code:

**urlpatterns** = [ **re_path**('prefixs/.*', your_ViewClass_name.as_view()), ]